# PHP code for user Login

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP and I have tried to create a user database system. User registration is working but user Authentication isn't working.

Here is the Registration code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","userdb");

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $phone_no=$_POST['phone_no'];
    $emailid=$_POST['emailid'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $statement= mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username, phone_no, emailid, password ) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    //string integer string string siss
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss" , $username, $phone_no, $emailid, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Here is the Login Code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","userdb");

    $usernm = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];

    $statement= mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    //string string ss
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss" , $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $username, $phone_no, $emailid, $password );
    $user = array();
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $user[username]=$username;
        $user[phone_no]=$phone_no;
        $user[emaild]=$emailid;
        $user[password]=$password;
        if($usernm==$username && $pwd==$password){
            echo"success";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: undefined variable x notices; that's what you should be seeing with error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly your problem

```
$usernm = $_POST['username'];    //<-- $usernm != $username used in bind param
$pwd=$_POST['password'];         //<-- ditto $password & $pwd

$statement= mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
//string string ss
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss" , $username, $password);
```

Change to this and see if that helps

```
$usernm = $_POST['username'];    //<-- $usernm != $username used in bind param
$pwd    = $_POST['password'];

$statement= mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
//string string ss
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss" , $usernm, $pwd);
```

> I see that you are not hashing the password before you store it onto your database. This is bad practice. Can I suggest you have a look at [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)
>   Leaving passwords unhashed allows internal staff the possibility of hacking user accounts.

Comment: so php cant guess what variables i want to use? shocking! ;-)

Comment: Ahh just wait for PHP10 then we will be in clover

Comment: so, error reporting (had it been set), would have, should have thrown an undefined variable notice, *ain't that right Sparky?* @Dagon

Comment: In PHP10, _THERE WILL BE NO SUCH THING AS AN ERROR_

Comment: oh, how so? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Pain today.... Jam tomorrow!